# Get All Answers With Tag - Stackoverflow API

Tags: support, api

The stackexchange API supports /users/{id}/tags/{tags}/top-answers which returns the top 30 answers a user has posted in response to questions with the given tags (see [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-user-answers-in-tags)). What query would I use to get all answers a user has posted in response to a certain tag? I tried /users/{id}/tags/{tags}/answers, but this is not a valid query.

Comment: The API returns the top **20** answerers, not 30 as claimed. There is an [open documentation bug](http://stackapps.com/q/4735) on that issue.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  However, I'm trying to get all answers, not just the top answers.  Is that possible? Reading through the docs, it seems to me that I would need to make multiple queries.

Comment: You really have to use the api? Or would using  http://data.stackexchange.com/ be an option?

Comment: @rene I need to use it in a script.  How would data.stackexchange.com help me?

Comment: If it is not real-time you could export the result of a query to CSV but that is basically it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to grab all answers posted by a user and then client-side filter that down to the tags you want.

You can pass `!9YdnSPSy.` as the filter to `/users/{ids}/answers` to make sure tags are included in the output in addition to the default properties of the [answer object](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer) or build a new filter by clicking "edit" [here](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users).

As a side note, API-related questions are usually best asked on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com).

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the proper site for future API questions.  This works nicely for my purpose.